# Prove that if $x^{nm}- a$ is irreducible then $x^n-a$ and $x^m-a$ is irreducible

Tags: polynomials

Let $a \neq 0$ and let $x^{nm}- a$ be a polynomial. Prove that if $x^{nm}- a$ is irreducible then $x^n-a$ and $x^m-a$ are irreducible.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Suppose that $x^{m}-a$ is reducible, then there exists $p,q$ s.t $x^m-a = p(x)q(x)$, with $\deg p $ and $\deg q<m$.

Now note that $x^{nm}-a = (x^n)^m - a = p(x^n)q(x^n)= r(x)s(x)$, then $x^{nm}-a$ is reducible.

My question is, $\deg r, \deg s < mn$??

Also, is that correct?

Comment: I think this is good. Since $p(x)$ has degree strictly less than $m$, the degree of $p(x^n)$ must be strictly less than $mn$. Likewise with $q(x)$.

Comment: Specifically: $\deg r = n\deg p$ and $\deg s=n\deg q$.